# Is there a term for mismatch between time and word order?

Tags: word-order

1. Is 'word order' the correct term?
2. Does anyone know of other examples from the literary canon?  I can think of merely one in English from [*As I Lay Dying* (1930)](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/William_Faulkner#As_I_Lay_Dying_(1930)):

   > I can remember how when I was young I believed death to be a phenomenon of the body; now I know it to be merely a function of the mind — and that of the minds who suffer the bereavement. **The nihilists say it is the end; the fundamentalists, the beginning**; when in reality it is no more than a single tenant or family moving out of a tenement or a town.

I'm not disapproving Faulkner's mismatch! I quote him merely to exhibit how the bolded phrase can be rewritten to match time and word order, and to forestall the necessity to reorder the sequence of events

> **The fundamentalists say it is the beginning; the nihilists, the end;**

Comment: As was mentioned the earlier time you asked this question (I forget where), it's a misanalysis to see "the end" in the context of this sentence as referring to something that occurs at a later point in time than "the beginning".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In literature and rhetoric, this is called **hysteron proteron** (Ancient Greek for "later earlier"). Probably the most famous example is Vergil's *Aeneid* II.353:

> *mori-ā-mur et in medi-a arm-a ru-ā-mus*
>   die-HORT-1PL and into middle-ACC.PL weapon-ACC.PL charge-HORT-1PL
>   "Let us die, and charge into the middle of the fight!"

The more general term is **hyperbaton**, which is any sort of "rearrangement" from the way you'd expect.